# Drupal search module - rendered pages instead of nodes?

Tags: drupal, search

Is there a module for Drupal that searches the final versions of the rendered pages (in the same way that Google would, for example) instead of all the nodes? The way I have set up my site involves views that display several nodes depending on what the page is. I don't want to search through each of the little boxes, but the finished version of the page instead.

Comment: I should add that I have looked at the "Search by Page" module and that doesn't seem to do what I need, although it is possible that I have it configured incorrectly.

Comment: Hm, I probably should have said that I was using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, you are searching for a way to index the dynamic view content, and keep the search index out of the individual nodes?

I think your best bet is https://drupal.org/project/search_config
A lot has been added to Drupal 7 core, so that many 'search restrict' modules are now obsolete.

If this is still not what you are looking for, and you feel a bit adventurous, you can find various guides from before this was incorporated, and go the way of custom code.  http://www.lullabot.com/articles/hiding-content-drupals-search-system
http://www.acquia.com/blog/drupal-search-how-indexing-works

If it is slick and stable, submit it back to the drupal community.  They will be your friends.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what I am looking for either, unfortunately. It's not so much that I need to keep the search index out of the nodes as I can't actually get it to index the dynamic view content. Basically I have a view on each page which pulls nodes of a certain custom type that have a field that is a node reference - that of the page that they belong on. So the 'page node' itself actually has no body content, and what is displayed is only the results of the views. But those results are not highly dynamic. I will probably end up using Google site search. (I was hoping to avoid the fee.)